# c++ std::sort function with customized comparator endless loop

Tags: c++, sorting

The following code is endless in https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

```
int size = 17;
vector<vector<int>> p = vector<vector<int>>(size,vector<int>(1,0));
sort(p.begin(), p.end(), [](vector<int> const& lhs, vector<int> const& rhs){
        return true;
    });
```

However, if you replace size from 17 to 14, it works.

Same thing happens on my local environment, it stops working when size exceed 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [comparator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) must induce a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), which yours does not. So your code has Undefined Behavior.